# F# PowerPack licence

Tags: f#, licensing, powerpack

I have a question on licensing FSharp PowerPack.

On the project page at [codeplex.com](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/license) is Apache license 2.0.
At the same time, after installation, in the folder with the PowerPack you can find license.rtf, which claims that product distributed under MS-PL.

Which license F# PowerPack is distributed under?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The license has changed from MS-PL to Apache 2.0 relatively recently (it was licensed under MS-PL previously and the [change announcement is here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/11/04/announcing-the-f-compiler-library-source-code-drop.aspx)). I think you can safely assume it is licensed under Apache 2.0, because this is what the team intends. As far as I can tell, this is just a packaging bug and the license distributed with the installation should be Apache 2.0 too.

I'm not a lawyer, but I think it may be possible to release the code under multiple different licenses if you own it, so it may be the case that legally, the installation is MS-PL licensed and online source is Apache 2 licensed. (Even if it isn't intentional.)

However, both licenses allow you to do essentially the same things, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you, Tomas! This was an important point about using the F# at work.